# Number of Exotic Bounties

Tags: destiny

I have just found an exotic bounty after turning in various other bounties, both Vanguard and Crucible, when I went to claim the bounty I had 3 different bounty choices...Does anyone know how many of these bounties there actually are? Meaning specific starting bounties not sub missions within the bounties... Since each bounty gives a specific piece of equipment is there a possible bounty for each piece?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a list of each exotic bounty and it's reward.  Note if you click on the bounty, it will tell you the steps required to complete it.

1. [**Shattered Memory Fragment**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Shattered_Memory_Fragment),
   Reward: [Pocket Infinity](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Pocket_Infinity) (Fusion Rifle)
2. [**A Dubious Task**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/A_Dubious_Task),
   Reward: [Invective](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Invective) (Shotgun)
3. [**Toland’s Legacy**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Toland%27s_Legacy),
   Reward: [Bad Juju](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Juju) (Pulse Rifle)
4. [**A Voice in the Wilderness**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/A_Voice_in_the_Wilderness),
   Reward: [Super Good Advice](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Good_Advice) (Machine Gun)
5. [**An Unknown Patron**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/An_Unknown_Patron),
   Reward: [Fate of All Fools](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_of_All_Fools) (Scout Rifle)
6. [**A Light in the Dark**](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/A_Light_in_the_Dark),
   Reward: [Thorn](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Thorn) (Hand Cannon)

That's a total of 6 exotic bounties that are known so far.

Comment: I'm going to wait a little bit on marking this as the answer but you seem to be right. Give it a link and it would be great.

Comment: @Dupree3 Updated as requested with links to each bounty and its steps as well as links to the rewarded exotic weapons

Comment: Just a fun fact...I have now gotten 3 of these since posting this question. Thorn, Invective, and Bad Juju. Also got another exotic from the nightfall on the moon, Truth.

Comment: It appears than specific bounties are locked to each char-type (Warlock/Hunter/Titan) as I've been given exotic bounties 4 times as a Warlock and only had the option of A Dubious Task, Toland's Legacy and A Light in the Dark each time. Is this true, and is it known which bounties are locked to Titan/Hunter?

Comment: @redsirius that's not true in my experience, sounds like you've just had bad luck

Comment: @turbo got a 5th and 6th exotic bounty the other day. I hadn't completed the 5th by the time the 6th one was offered - and I only had 2 exotic bounty choices instead of three. (the missing option was the one I already had). Makes me more certain the 3 options might be locked.

Answer (score -1):

I just recieved my first exotic bounty last night, I currently just got to about Rank 2 and 3/4th the way to rank 3. I only really did Crucible bounties, with a few others aswell. I hope this helps and gives you a time frame as to when you can get one, unless its completely random.